# verification of certificate chain using openssl verify command

Tags: authentication, openssl

When attempting to verify google server's certificate chain using openssl, I am getting error.

Extract google's server and intermediate certificates:

> $ echo | openssl s_client -showcerts -connect www.google.com:443 | sed
>   -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p' > /tmp/server_certs.crt

Extract google's root CA from jdk:

> $ pwd
>
> /cygdrive/c/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_231/jre/lib/security
>
> $ keytool -export -keystore cacerts -storepass changeit -alias 'globalsignr2ca [jdk]' -file /cygwin64/tmp/google_root.der
>
> $ openssl x509 -in /tmp/google_root.der -out /tmp/google_root.pem -inform der

Also extracted google's root certificate from chrome browser to /tmp/google-chrome-root.pem. Doing a diff between chrome's root certificate and jdk extracted root certificate, there is no difference

> $ diff /tmp/google_root.pem /tmp/google-chrome-root.pem
>
> $
>   Based on this, I know, I am using the right root certificate.

Invoke openssl verify

> $ openssl verify -CAfile /tmp/google_root.pem /tmp/server_certs.crt
>
> C = US, ST = California, L = Mountain View, O = Google LLC, CN = www.google.com
>
> error 20 at 0 depth lookup: unable to get local issuer certificate
>   error /tmp/server_certs.crt: verification failed

I know verification through

> $ openssl s_client -showcerts -servername www.google.com -connect www.google.com:443

is successful

```
CONNECTED(00000005) depth=2 OU = GlobalSign Root CA - R2, O =
GlobalSign, CN = GlobalSign verify return:1 depth=1 C = US, O = Google
Trust Services, CN = GTS CA 1O1 verify return:1 depth=0 C = US, ST =
California, L = Mountain View, O = Google LLC, CN = www.google.com
verify return:1
```

and was expecting a similar successful result through the openssl verify command as well.

I am doing this exercise in windows 10 and cygwin.

Comment: What is the error?  And what is your actual question?

Comment: `openssl verify` takes only _one_ cert (NOT a chain) from the (or each) operand file; dupe https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/163577/should-a-server-or-a-client-be-able-to-verify-a-client-server-certificate-inte and cross https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/354195/download-and-verify-certificate-chain and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44375300/openssl-verify-with-chained-ca-and-chained-cert (all findable by searching "unable to get local issuer" BTW).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**TL;DR: You need to give `openssl verify` the intermediate certificate, too.**

Your manual verification:

```
$ openssl verify -CAfile /tmp/google_root.pem /tmp/server_certs.crt
```

Does not specify the intermediate cert.  When you perform the verification using s_client, it shows that there are three certs - root, intermediate, and server.  I've indented your output to make this more obvious:

```
CONNECTED(00000005) 
  depth=2 OU = GlobalSign Root CA - R2, O = GlobalSign, CN = GlobalSign verify return:1 
    depth=1 C = US, O = Google Trust Services, CN = GTS CA 1O1 verify return:1 
      depth=0 C = US, ST = California, L = Mountain View, O = Google LLC, CN = www.google.com verify return:1
```

In order for `openssl verify` to work, you need to download that intermediate cert (`CN = GTS CA 101`) and pass it in the [command line](http://openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man1/openssl-verify.html) using the `-untrusted` argument:

> `-untrusted file`
>
> A file of untrusted certificates. The file should contain multiple
>   certificates in PEM format concatenated together.

Something like this:

```
$ openssl verify -CAfile /tmp/google_root.pem -untrusted /tmp/google_intermediate.pem /tmp/server_certs.crt
```

Comment: Changed my command to : $ openssl verify -untrusted /tmp/server_certs.crt -CAfile /tmp/google_root.pem /tmp/server_certs.crt and it works.